# PowerBI Removing top rows by applied steps in PowerBI skips rows of multiple files

Tags: powerbi

I have multiple Excel files in one folder and I loaded the entire folder to PowerBI. The first Excel file is the sample file to PowerBI and I applied some formatting steps to this table of which one of those is to remove the top three rows. PowerBI should now remove the three top rows of all other Excel files in this folder too now. However, I see that of some Excel files it only removes 1 row. Does anybody know what causes this? Thanks in advance.

[image: This picture shows the applied steps]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably caused by inconsistent Excel files. The most common issue that would cause the behavior you describe is hidden rows in Excel, which Power BI will read as data rows.  But hey - it's Excel so the users could've done almost anything.

You can edit the **Sample File** query to point it at the file with issues which might give you more insight.

More generally I would say that is a fragile query design, instead I would try to filter on a column e.g. Remove Empty.

Answer (score 0):

It was caused by the fact that the merging of all Excel files happens before the Top 3 Rows were removed, resulting in the fact that only the first three rows of the total merged table were removed.